Implement Registration and Login with SMS OTP in a Single Form - keycloak
I want to create a form for both registration and login using SMS OTP in keycloak. The idea is that the user enters their mobile number, clicks on "Send Code," and an OTP is sent to them. If the user is not registered, they will be signed up and logged in. If they are already registered, the system will only log them in.
Could you please guide me on how to implement this?

From my understanding,
Flow 01:

Set up a twilio or any service to sent otp
create a maven project with dependencies

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
     <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
     <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
     <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
     <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>

https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html
In Maven project custom service provider for the keycloak, generate the jar provide to the keycloak
Here in SPI,
i) create custom otp.ftl file, that will render after the register page.
    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    
        Response challenge = context.form()
                .createForm("otp-login.ftl");
        context.challenge(challenge);
    }


ii) public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {} for action perform the otp logic
iii) on success redirect to the next page
In keycloak Customization
i) In Keycloak admin console you have authentication-> registration flow
ii) customize the registration flow for registration
iii) for login customize the browser flow
For implementing custom spi:
Implement custom SPI in Keycloak
